# Use one webcam for two devices via KVM switch

Tags: usb, hdmi, webcam, kvm-switch, conferencing

We have our meeting-/ conference-rooms equipped with a Logitech Meetup USB webcam. This device is connected to a computer and a big screen in the room. So far so good. We use a HDMI switch to give people the possibility to use the big screen for presentations with a laptop/ mobile device. We now tried multiple HMDI+USB switches (e.g. [AIMOS HDMI KVM Switch](https://www.amazon.de/dp/B07QYRCYQQ/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_tai_O0XkEbA36GQ6R)) to also make the USB webcam available when using a laptop. But non of the switches we tried was able to connect the cam to the PC or to a laptop. Regardless wether the switch has its own power-supply or not.
Any ideas which hardware to use that his setup can work?

Comment: i use a cheap usb switcher for something like that. it's _supposed_ to be for switching 4 devices on one PC, but it works just fine "backwards" to switch a whole downstream usb hub of devices between two+ systems.

Comment: Well, I thought that the AIMOS would be something like a HDMI switch with a „cheap USB switcher“ included... But anyhow, since this works for you we‘ll try it with a separate USB switcher in „the other“ direction on Monday. Thanks for your answer. Do you have a solution for switching both switches at the same time then or do you manually switch them separately?

Comment: it's a two step for me: 1. change monitor input  2. switch usb